# What is the best practice for checking undefined property in chained object form?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I'm implementing `a.b.c.d` on separate file.

So, I need to check a,b,c is defined and fallback into catch clause when those property is not defined.

Currently, I'm using this code. But it's too long, dirty and hard to maintain.

```
try{
  if(!("a" in window)) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  if(!("b" in a)) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  if(!("c" in a.b)) {
    throw new Error();
  }
} catch(e){ }
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: Do you want to know exactly which one doesn't exist?

Comment: @Linek What if I say yes?

Comment: You might look at [*Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/11922384#11922384). Define "best practice", it depends on your criteria for "best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manually throwing an error in each of those cases, but the behaviour when you try to access a property of `undefined` is to throw a ReferenceError anyway, so you can just catch that instead:

```
try{
  a.b.c.d
} catch(e){ // Either a, a.b, or a.b.c was undefined }
```

Comment: Since you caught the [*error*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), you can also look at the message, e.g. `Cannot read property 'd' of undefined`. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
if !(a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d) {
  throw new Error();
}
// else a.b.c.d exists
```

Comment: Except that if `a.b.c.d` exists and has a falsey value, this will throw an error (not my down vote BTW).